# How to use Ubuntu QML Dialog or other Popup without any buttons?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch, qml, dialog

I am trying to make a modal popup where all there is is a progress bar, and when the progress bar is full it automatically closes, `Dialog` and the other popups don't seem to even show unless you set them up with buttons (not including `Popover`, that's too far off from what I want), is there a way I could get `Dialog` or `DefaultSheet` to work without any buttons?

Or else how can I make my own popup with `PopupBase`? That's what I'm prepared to do now, just not sure how, I know I would need to create a file `MyPopup.qml`, which then I could do:

```
MyPopup { stuff goes here }
```

But in MyPopup.qml would I do this?

```
PopupBase { MyPopup contents go here }
```

Wouldn't that be using it directly (API page says not to use it directly), and if so, how do you "inherit" `PopupBase` to create your own `Popup`?

If my question is confusing please let me know and I'll try to clarify.

Comment: I think you typed the question in the wrong window... this is not a Ubuntu question, is it?

Comment: I think not, possibly a question regarding ubuntu touch development

Comment: Yes, but I have seen several other questions here regarding Ubuntu Touch development, the Ubuntu Forums don't seem to have a lot of traffic, this is the only place I can really post questions about this.

Considering this is an Ubuntu specific development question, regarding Ubuntu's own QML APIs, I think it's an appropriate place to post.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I found an answer to my own question, I believe I am going to have to make my own dialog inheriting `PopupBase`, and it is as simple as having `PopupBase {}` as the root element in my `MyDialog.qml` file. I know because I found the actual `Dialog.qml` file from the Ubuntu QML library, and that's exactly how they did it.